# Can't unmarshal marshalled document when default namespace used

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink

I set up a repo which shows my problem: https://github.com/Waxolunist/stackoverflow.34392476

I try to unmarshal a simple xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<for:document xmlns:for="http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrenderer/forwktbx">
     <Export xmlns="urn:adcubum:Syrius">
         <ExportInhalt/>
         <ExportKopf>
             <Quelle>lokal</Quelle>
         </ExportKopf>
         <SchemaVersion>bec811a9807a8c8da403d70b9b5e22ad</SchemaVersion>
     </Export>
</for:document>
```

This is the document I get from following code:

```
    Document document = new Document();
    Export export = new Export();
    ExportKopf exportKopf = new ExportKopf();
    exportKopf.setQuelle("lokal");
    export.setExportKopf(exportKopf);
    ExportInhalt exportInhalt = new ExportInhalt();
    export.setExportInhalt(exportInhalt);
    export.setSchemaVersion("bec811a9807a8c8da403d70b9b5e22ad");
    document.setExport(export);

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.marshal(document, System.out);
```

Document looks as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "document", namespace = "http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrenderer/forwktbx")
public class Document {

    @XmlElement(name = "Export", namespace = "urn:adcubum:Syrius")
    private vo.dom.common_service.modul_bl.syrius.Export export;

}
```

package-info.java

```
@XmlSchema(
namespace = "urn:adcubum:Syrius",
xmlns = {
    @XmlNs(prefix = "for", namespaceURI = "http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrenderer/forwktbx"),
    @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "urn:adcubum:Syrius")
}, 
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)
```

When I try to unmarshal it, I don't get the data mapped:

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/requests/document_simple3.xml");
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xmlsr = factory.createXMLStreamReader(is);

    Document document = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlsr, Document.class).getValue();
```

ExportKopf and ExportInhalt are returning null.

Instead following xml works. The only difference is the namespace prefix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<for:document xmlns:for="http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrenderer/forwktbx">
    <ns3:Export xmlns:ns3="urn:adcubum:Syrius">
        <ExportInhalt/>
        <ExportKopf>
            <Quelle>lokal</Quelle>
        </ExportKopf>
        <SchemaVersion>bec811a9807a8c8da403d70b9b5e22ad</SchemaVersion>
    </ns3:Export>
</for:document>
```

I am using eclipselink moxy.

What do I have to change, so that unmarshaling the marshaled document works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's always a good idea to see the actual XSD schema of your mapping whenever something strange like this is happening in JAXB. You could easily do that with the following code.

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document.class);
jaxbContext.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

    @Override
    public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new PrintWriter(System.err) {
            @Override
            public void close() {
            }
        });
        streamResult.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
        return streamResult;
    }
});
```

That will print the schema(s) that should reflect your JAXB model (you can use another writer to write them to a file). The XSD files are usually very revealing about these kind of issues. I think the problem in your case is the `@XmlSchema` mapping. You should try to use `elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` instead. It's always a good idea to use `QUALIFIED` whenever you're working with multiple namespaces in your mapping.

**EDIT**: while the main problem with your JAXB mapping was the wrong and/or missing value for the `elementFormDefault` there were other things that had to be fixed for the code in your repo to work.

- the `Export` element in the `Document` was missing a namespace declaration (from your example, the `Document` and `Export` elements are parts of different namespaces)
- missing `elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` from the `export` package
- wrong namespace value for your main package `@XmlSchema` annotation (was `urn:stackoverflow:exportnamespace` instead of `urn:stackoverflow:documentnamespace` in which the `Document` element should be)
- wrong import for `jdk_jaxb/UnmarshallerTest.java` - it was importing the `model.eclipselink.Document` instead of `model.sun.Document`

Comment: I fixed your code in the github repo as well, made a pull request for it so that you can find it. Here's my clone: https://github.com/nfekete/stackoverflow.34392476/commit/3b980248b05403a51b9b53c90176bc5361772b9a

Comment: This question might help you with the qualified vs unqualified value for the `elementFormDefault`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463138/what-does-elementformdefault-do-for-xml-when-is-it-used

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Here's the updated code https://github.com/MojoJojo/stackoverflow.34392476**

Okay, here's the working version with all moxy_jaxb test passing. Because you said you are using moxy, I left out the changes for model.sun.* packages. If you understand the concept below, you should be able to fix it easily on your own.

First, I cleaned up namespace declarations in your mode.* packages. Most of the times, the declarations and bindings inside package-info.java suffice. Declaring them over and over again on package, entities, fields will add to complexity and unwanted behavior. Check out [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/moxy/type_level002.htm) for details. There is no need to re-declare them on the individual Models/Entities themselves, unless there is a strong reason to do otherwise. Next, the test xml itself was a little broken. Fixed the test xml with proper prefixes wherever necessary:

First, model.eclipselink.Document.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "document")
public class Document {
    @XmlElement(name = "Export", namespace="urn:adcubum:Syrius")
    private Export export;
    public Export getExport() {
        return export;
    }
    public void setExport(Export export) {
        this.export = export;
    }
}
```

model.eclipselink.package-info.java:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrenderer/forwktbx",
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package model.eclipselink;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Similar refactoring on model.eclipselink.export.packageinfo.java:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "urn:adcubum:Syrius",
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package model.eclipselink.export;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.Xml
```

And on Export.java:

```
package model.eclipselink.export;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlElementNillable;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Export")

@XmlType(name = "Export", propOrder = {
        "exportInhalt",
        "exportKopf",
        "schemaVersion"
    })
public class Export {

    @XmlElement(name = "ExportKopf", required = true)
    private ExportKopf exportKopf;

    @XmlElement(name = "ExportInhalt", required = true)
    private ExportInhalt exportInhalt;

    @XmlElement(name = "SchemaVersion", required = true)
    private String schemaVersion;

    public ExportKopf getExportKopf() {
        return exportKopf;
    }

    public void setExportKopf(ExportKopf exportKopf) {
        this.exportKopf = exportKopf;
    }

    public ExportInhalt getExportInhalt() {
        return exportInhalt;
    }

    public void setExportInhalt(ExportInhalt exportInhalt) {
        this.exportInhalt = exportInhalt;
    }

    public String getSchemaVersion() {
        return schemaVersion;
    }

    public void setSchemaVersion(String schemaVersion) {
        this.schemaVersion = schemaVersion;
    }

}
```

And the few tweaks to your xml files for prefixes.Here's document_prefix.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<for:document xmlns:for="http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrenderer/forwktbx">
    <ns1:Export xmlns:ns1="urn:adcubum:Syrius">
        <ns1:ExportKopf>
            <ns1:Quelle>lokal</ns1:Quelle>
        </ns1:ExportKopf>
        <ns1:ExportInhalt/>
        <ns1:SchemaVersion>bec811a9807a8c8da403d70b9b5e22ad</ns1:SchemaVersion>
    </ns1:Export>
</for:document>
```

document.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<for:document
    xmlns:for="http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrenderer/forwktbx" xmlns="urn:adcubum:Syrius">
    <Export>
        <ExportKopf>
            <Quelle>lokal</Quelle>
        </ExportKopf>
        <ExportInhalt />
        <SchemaVersion>bec811a9807a8c8da403d70b9b5e22ad</SchemaVersion>
    </Export>
</for:document>
```

and document_realnamespace.xml (Not sure what the purpose of this file is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<for:document xmlns:ns1="urn:adcubum:Syrius" xmlns:for="http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrenderer/forwktbx">
    <ns1:Export>
        <ns1:ExportKopf>
            <ns1:Quelle>lokal</ns1:Quelle>
        </ns1:ExportKopf>
        <ns1:ExportInhalt/>
        <ns1:SchemaVersion>bec811a9807a8c8da403d70b9b5e22ad</ns1:SchemaVersion>
    </ns1:Export>
</for:document>
```

And you run mvn clean test:

```
Running moxy_jaxb.MarshallerTest
Context class: class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document xmlns="http://www.adcubum.com/wsdl/global/callout/syrius/modul_bl/doc/service/documentrend
erer/forwktbx" xmlns:ns0="urn:adcubum:Syrius">
   <ns0:Export>
      <ns0:ExportInhalt/>
      <ns0:ExportKopf>
         <ns0:Quelle>lokal</ns0:Quelle>
      </ns0:ExportKopf>
      <ns0:SchemaVersion>bec811a9807a8c8da403d70b9b5e22ad</ns0:SchemaVersion>
   </ns0:Export>
</document>
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.044 sec
Running moxy_jaxb.UnmarshallerTest
Context class: class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
lokal
Context class: class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
lokal
Context class: class org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext
lokal
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.033 sec
```