# problems with xml schema reference

Tags: xml

My xml schema and my xml document are both valid and well-formed. But there is still a problem with the correct reference. I looked up a few similar questions but I can`t solve my problem.

Beginning of the xml schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">


<xs:element name="catalog"/>
```

xml schema example:

```
<xs:element name="Qstr">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

beginning of xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<catalog xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com   file:///home/n/workspace/webprog1/WebContent/schema.xml">

<Qstr>
    <text>random question?</text>
    <a>asdfasd</a>
    <b>ertwetrewt</b>
    <c>ghkghk</c>
    <d>xcvbxcbbx</d>
</Qstr>
```

Error message:

```
 Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.w3schools.com":text}'. One of '{text}' is expected.
```

Comment: Show the part of the schema that talks about "text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for **elementFormDefault** is **unqualified**.  Because you're using a default namespace with `<catalog>`, all child elements will also take on the same namespace, instead of no namespace (which is what you want).

E.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463138/what-does-elementformdefault-do-for-xml-when-is-it-used) for more info.

It will probably (you didn't paste the full XSD) work if you change to something like:

```
<myns:catalog xmlns:myns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com   file:///home/n/workspace/webprog1/WebContent/schema.xml">

<myns:Qstr>
    <text>random question?</text>
    <a>asdfasd</a>
    <b>ertwetrewt</b>
    <c>ghkghk</c>
    <d>xcvbxcbbx</d>
</myns:Qstr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I set elementFormDefault to "qualified", now I`m getting no errors. My actual problem(transforming the xml file to html) isn`t solved yet, but I already asked about that in another question.

Comment: OK, if it helped please accept or at least vote up the answer.  Thanks.