# Why does XSD validation expect {element} with braces rather than just element?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

When I try to validate the below XML against the below XSD I get the following error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element >'personal'. One of '{personal} expected.

### XML

```
<main xmlns = "http://www.example.com"
      xmlns:xsi = "https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation = "main.xsd">
  <personal>
    <full-name>John Smith</full-name>
    <contact>
      <street-address>12345 Example Street</street-address>
      <city>Somewhere</city>
      <state>EX</state>
      <postal-code>111 111</postal-code>
      <phone>123 456 7890</phone>
      <email>myemail@example.com</email>
    </contact>
  </personal>
</main>
```

### XSD

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace = "http://www.example.com"
            xmlns = "http://www.example.com">
  <xsd:element name = "main" type = "main-type"/>

  <xsd:complexType name = "main-type">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name = "personal" type = "personal-type"/>
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name = "personal-type">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name = "full-name" type = "xsd:string" 
                   minOccurs = "1"/>
      <xsd:element name = "contact" type = "contact-type" 
                   minOccurs = "1"/>
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <!--Different xsd:strings for contact information in contact-type-->
  <xsd:complexType name = "contact-type">
    <xsd:all>
      <xsd:element name = "street-address" type = "xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name = "city" type = "xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name = "state" type = "xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name = "postal-code" type = "xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name = "phone" type = "xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name = "email" type = "xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:all>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML as posted has two preliminary problems ahead of the error message you've posted:

1. Change

   ```
   xmlns:xsi = "https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   ```

   to

   ```
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   xsi:schemaLocation = "main.xsd"
   ```

   to

   ```
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.example.com main.xsd"
   ```

---

Now, your posted XML and XSD actually will be in a state to exhibit your posted problem:

> [Error] main.xml:4:13: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was
>   found starting with element 'personal'. One of '{personal}' is
>   expected.

**Explanation:** This error is telling you that `personal` is expected to be in no namespace according to your XSD; the `{` and `}` in `One of '{personal}' is expected` indicates this.

You might think that since your XSD declares  `targetNamespace="http://www.example.com"` that all of its components are thus placed into the `http://www.example.com` namespace.  This is not true of locally declared components, however ***unless you set `elementFormDefault="qualified"`*** -- the default is `unqualified`.

### Locally declared elements are in *no namespace* by default

Therefore, make one last change:  Add

```
elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

to the `xsd:schema` element, and then your XML valid against your XSD.

**See also** [**this answer about what elementFormDefault means**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758277/290085).