# XML validation error: expecting a tag that already exists

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am developing an XML communication tool. My first step is to validate de xml I am receving. 
The communication is meant for V2G, so the xsd is on the web.
I downloades the schemas an used a free web validator to check the message, but i get an error and i can not se the reason (i am new in xml).

the schema is as follows:

```
<!-- This XML document originates from the ISO/IEC 15118-2 standard which can be obtained from ISO at http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=55366 -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="urn:iso:15118:2:2010:AppProtocol"
    targetNamespace="urn:iso:15118:2:2010:AppProtocol">
    <xs:element name="supportedAppProtocolReq">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="AppProtocol" type="AppProtocolType" maxOccurs="20"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="supportedAppProtocolRes">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ResponseCode" type="responseCodeType"/>
                <xs:element name="SchemaID" type="idType" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="AppProtocolType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ProtocolNamespace" type="protocolNamespaceType"/>
            <xs:element name="VersionNumberMajor" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="VersionNumberMinor" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
            <xs:element name="SchemaID" type="idType"/>
            <xs:element name="Priority" type="priorityType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="idType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedByte"/>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="protocolNameType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="protocolNamespaceType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:anyURI">
            <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="priorityType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedByte">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="20"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="responseCodeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="OK_SuccessfulNegotiation"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="OK_SuccessfulNegotiationWithMinorDeviation"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Failed_NoNegotiation"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

And the messages is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<supportedAppProtocolReq xmlns="urn:iso:15118:2:2010:AppProtocol" xmlns:xsi="urn:iso:15118:2:2010:AppProtocol">
    <AppProtocol>
        <ProtocolNamespace>urn:din:70121:2012:MsgDef</ProtocolNamespace>
        <VersionNumberMajor>2</VersionNumberMajor>
        <VersionNumberMinor>1</VersionNumberMinor>
        <SchemaID>0</SchemaID>
        <Priority>1</Priority>
    </AppProtocol>
</supportedAppProtocolReq>
```

The error i get is:

> Error - Line 3, 14: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3;
>   columnNumber: 14; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found
>   starting with element 'AppProtocol'. One of '{AppProtocol}' is
>   expected.

So, as I can understand, the invalid tag is the same tag that is asking for.
Surely is a simple thing, but this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Either duplicate link will help, but for the second, see specifically [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758277/290085).  Search for *WTF* and read the part about not being the first developer to curse this error message.  ;-)

Comment: add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to `schema` attributes in xsd

Comment: Ok, thank you, i'll check the links