# XSD error: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have an XML file that need to be validate with the XSD file, but when I got this error when I want to validate my XML with XSD file

> Cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid Content Was Found Starting With Element 'ClientData'. One Of 
>    '`{"http://www.myTest/xml/Import/user/data":ClientData}`' Is Expected., Line '2', Column '27'.

This is my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prefix:UteXmlComunicazione xmlns:prefix="http://www.myTest/xml/Import/user/data">
    <ClientData>
        <client>
            <pfPg>PF</pfPg>
            <Family>Alex White</Family>
            <name></name>
        </client>
        <vendor>
            <Timeperiod>
                <NumberofFactor></NumberofFactor>
                <year>2018</year>
            </Timeperiod>
            <Address>
                <Address1>
                    <top>Via</top>
                    <street>DANTE</street>
                    <number>108</number>
                    <Zipcode>20776</Zipcode>
                    <Code>033032</Code>
                </Address1>
            </Address>
        </vendor>
    </ClientData>
</prefix:UteXmlComunicazione>
```

and this is the XSD

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.myTest/xml/Import/user/data" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="UteXmlComunicazione">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ClientData" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="client" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="pfPg"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Family"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="vendor" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TimePeriod" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element type="xs:short" name="year"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="NumberofFactor"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Address" minOccurs="0">
```

I have no idea what is the issue...Could you please let me know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate error is due to `ClientData` not being in the target namespace of the XSD.  It appears that you intended to declare a default namespace on the root element, but you only changed the namespace of the root element.

Change

```
<prefix:UteXmlComunicazione xmlns:prefix="http://www.myTest/xml/Import/user/data">
```

to

```
<UteXmlComunicazione xmlns="http://www.myTest/xml/Import/user/data">
```

to fix your immediate error.

Here is an updated copy of your XML that will validate against an updated copy of your XSD.  (The `Address` element has been elided since you've not included its definition in your XSD, and it's not worth building out here.)

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UteXmlComunicazione 
    xmlns="http://www.myTest/xml/Import/user/data"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.myTest/xml/Import/user/data try.xsd"
    >
  <ClientData>
    <client>
      <pfPg>PF</pfPg>
      <Family>Alex White</Family>
      <name></name>
    </client>
    <vendor>
      <TimePeriod>
        <year>2018</year>
        <NumberofFactor>0</NumberofFactor>
      </TimePeriod>
    </vendor>
  </ClientData>
</UteXmlComunicazione>
```

### XSD

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           targetNamespace="http://www.myTest/xml/Import/user/data"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="UteXmlComunicazione">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ClientData" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="client" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="pfPg"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Family"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="vendor" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="TimePeriod" minOccurs="0">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element type="xs:short" name="year"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="NumberofFactor"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Hi, Actually I added the prefix because if I dont mention the prefix in my root element, I see this error: Cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'UteXmlComunicazione'., Line '1', Column '113'.

Comment: That's a different problem.  Use whatever mechanism your validating XML parser has to associate your XML doc with your XSD, or provide a hint in your XML via `schemaLocation`.   See [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085).

Comment: (Note that I've shown how to use `schemaLocation` in the sample XML of this answer, but see the link in the above comment for a detailed explanation of the mechanism.)

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if I got your point... ```schemaLocation ``` should be the name of my XSD file? means that try.xsd should be the name of my XSD file...Since I do not have access to the validation system of our user, I validate it with online free tool. I try to set it as the name of my XSD file but I see all the error not only just for  ```clientData ```, but also for the other elements.... Maybe the Online tool is not working good?

Comment: No, `try.xsd` is just an example; use the name of your own XSD.  If the online tool has a way to associate an XSD with an XML file, then you won't even need `schemaLocation`.

Answer (score 1):

In the XSD you have `elementFormDefault="qualified"` this makes it so all elements needs to be qualified and not only the root element. Seeing there is no `prefix` on your `ClientData` in the XML this does not work.

So or make all elements qualified in the XML or change de XSD elementFormDefault value.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_schema.asp

> elementFormDefault    Optional. The form for elements declared in the
>   target namespace of this schema. The value must be "qualified" or
>   "unqualified". Default is "unqualified". "unqualified" indicates that
>   elements from the target namespace are not required to be qualified
>   with the namespace prefix. "qualified" indicates that elements from
>   the target namespace must be qualified with the namespace prefix

Comment: Thanks Nick, so you mean that I need to add prefix for all my elements?

Comment: This is not the actual problem.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61912809/290085)  for details about what's really wrong.

Comment: And see [this explanation about what `elementFormDefault` means](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758277/290085)

Comment: sinaei that is possible. But setting the default namespace as @kjhughes suggested is a cleaner solution.