# Impact of changing elementFormDefault="unqualified" to "qualified" in XSD File

Tags: xml, xsd

We have an XSD file that has no `elementFormatDefault`, means that `elementFormDefault="unqualified"`.
But we have an issue with creating the `XML` that is valid with respect to the XSD.

We asked our support to change the XSD and add this attribute, but they mentioned they cannot change the header of the XSD...

As I found, `elementFormDefault` just has impact on local variables, so the variables that are inside the XSD. I want to know what is the impact of changing `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` to `elementFormDefault="qualified"`.

I mean, if they also change it, it has no impact, am I right?

Can anyone explain and confirm my assumptions?

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758277/290085) in particular on the duplicate Q/A link for an extensive explanation of `elementFormatDefault`.

Comment: Thanks, so if I am not wrong it has no impact. but I did not understand how can I add  xmlns="" to my attributes. for example this is one of my line  <dichiarazione_impianto xmlns="" codice_impianto="1411">. how can I add it to codice_impianto attribute?