# How to add targetNamespace to XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I want to use namespace in XML file. Current code working fine without a namespace using `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

(Working Code)
test-document.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root-element
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./test-schema.xsd">
    <sizeElement>T1 T2 T1</sizeElement>
</root-element>
```

test-schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="root-element">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="sizeElement" type="sizeList"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="size">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:enumeration value="T1"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="T2"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="sizeList">
        <xs:list itemType="size" />
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

But when i try to add **targettargetNamespace="ns"** in **<<xs:schema>>** tag as attribute
it showing error At:

```
<xs:list itemType="size" />
```

ERROR:

> src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'size' to a(n) 'type definition' component.xsd(src-resolve)

I am using vs-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple concepts involved with validating XML in a namespace:

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [What does elementFormDefault do in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1463138/290085)

Here are the above concepts applied to your XML and XSD:

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root-element
    xmlns="http://example.com/ns"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/ns test-schema.xsd">
    <sizeElement>T1 T2 T1</sizeElement>
</root-element>
```

### XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="http://example.com/ns"
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/ns">
  <xs:element name="root-element">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="sizeElement" type="sizeList"/>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="size">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:enumeration value="T1"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="T2"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="sizeList">
    <xs:list itemType="size" />
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

The above XML is valid against the above XSD.