# How to link XML file with XSD schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am new to XML. Can somebody help me connect the XSD to XML file ?

Here is my XML:

```
<WorldWideHappiness
    xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/xml Hapiness.xsd">
<Record>
    <Country>
        <Name>The Netherlands</Name>
        <Region>Western Europe</Region>
        <HappinessRank>7</HappinessRank>
        <HappinessScore>7.339</HappinessScore>
        <LowerConfidenceInterval>7.284</LowerConfidenceInterval>
        <UpperConfidenceInterval>7.394</UpperConfidenceInterval>
        <Health>0.81231</Health>
    </Country>
</Record>
</WorldWideHappiness>
```

And here is my XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com">
<xs:element name="WorldWideHappiness" type="WorldWideStatistics"/>
    <xs:complexType name="WorldWideStatistics">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Country" type="CountryType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="CountryType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="Region" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="HappinessRank" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="HappinessScore" type="xs:double"/>
        <xs:element name="LowerConfidenceInterval" type="xs:double"/>
        <xs:element name="UpperConfidenceInterval" type="xs:double"/>
        <xs:element name="Health" type="xs:double"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Would you prefer to change your XML or XSD?

Comment: I believe something is wrong with my XML so I want to change the XML file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixes needed include

1. Match the namespace in the XML with the targetnamespace of the XSD (check) and one of the namespace-file pairs in `xsi:schemaLocation` (fix).
2. Add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the XSD.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758277/290085) for why.
3. Fix `Name` in XML to match XSD type.

Altogether, the following XML is valid against the following XSD:

### XML

```
<WorldWideHappiness
        xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com Hapiness.xsd">
    <Country>
        <Name>1</Name>
        <Region>Western Europe</Region>
        <HappinessRank>7</HappinessRank>
        <HappinessScore>7.339</HappinessScore>
        <LowerConfidenceInterval>7.284</LowerConfidenceInterval>
        <UpperConfidenceInterval>7.394</UpperConfidenceInterval>
        <Health>0.81231</Health>
    </Country>
</WorldWideHappiness>
```

### XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com">
  <xs:element name="WorldWideHappiness" type="WorldWideStatistics"/>
  <xs:complexType name="WorldWideStatistics">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Country" type="CountryType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CountryType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="Region" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="HappinessRank" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:element name="HappinessScore" type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="LowerConfidenceInterval" type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="UpperConfidenceInterval" type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="Health" type="xs:double"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### See also

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Thanks, @YitzhakKhabinsky.