# Possible namespace problem during XML validation

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation, xml-validation

The following XML with XSD causes the validation error:

> The element 'choices' in namespace `'http://www.test.it'` has invalid child element 'choice' in namespace `'http://www.test.it'`. List of possible elements expected: 'choice'.

This is `choices.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<choices xmlns="http://www.test.it"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsd:schemaLocation="http://www.test.it ./schema/choices.xsd">
    <choice>yes</choice>
</choices>
```

This is `schema/choices.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema  xmlns="http://www.test.it"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://www.test.it">

    <xs:simpleType name="yes_or_no_t">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="yes" />
            <xs:enumeration value="no" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="choices" >
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="choice" type="yes_or_no_t" />
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I must keep the `xmlns="http://www.test.it"` in the XML. The XML and XSD are meant to be local files (not published via network). I would rather keep the XSDs in a `schema` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems...

### Finding the XSD

Use `xsi:schemaLocation` for namespaced XML such as yours, not `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

**See also:**

- [How to link XML to XSD using schemaLocation or noNamespaceSchemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085)
- [How to reference a local XML Schema file correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253402/290085)

### Qualified elements

Add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the schema element of your XSD.

**See also:**

- [What does elementFormDefault do in XSD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1463138/290085)